# Operating Systems,Unix

Tags: unix, operating-system

The process is in either user mode or kernel mode based on this fact i want to ask that how process in user mode can map virtual address to physical address when it has no access to uarea.

Comment: are you talking about ia32 pagination?

Comment: no i m talking about the concept of actual loading of process & its execution.

Answer (score 3):

A user-mode process isn't supposed to know about physical addresses. That's the whole point of virtual memory.

EDIT:
It seems you're asking how a userspace program knows where to put it's data. It doesn't. It pretends it has the whole address space (0-4GB on x86) and the Operating System does whatever address translation is necessary to let the process pretend that.

Comment: can u please elaborate on your answer?